# Nest let syntax from ocaml

Tags: syntax, rust

I'm just starting to learn Rust and I'm coming from an OCaml background.

One thing that I often use is nested `let` expressions, in order to group related code together.

```
let x = 
  let y = 42 in
  y + 1
in
...
```

My naive translation of this to rust would be:

```
let x = 
  let y = 42;
  y + 1
;
```

However this fails to compile.

Is this type of syntax possible, or is it heavily frowned upon and thus is not supported?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust uses curly braces to delimit scopes. This works fine:

```rust
let x = {
  let y = 42;
  y + 1
};
```